# Timeline animations

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, html, animation

I recently made [this campus timeline](http://ucsd.edu/timeline/) for my university. When viewing the timeline on a mobile device (not a tablet), the navbar changes so that you can jump to the previous or next decade by clicking one of the arrows.

I'm concerned about the performance of the animation. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S3 (one of the most powerful Android phones out) but it's still extremely sluggish in both Chrome and Dolphin browser. How can I make it faster? The code that controls the jump and animation can be viewed here:

```
$timeline.find(".dec-banner").on("click", "a", function(event) { // bring user to previous or next decade if clicked on in the decade header
    var $navlink = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("decade-jump-prev")) {
        $("html,body").stop(true, true).animate({scrollTop: $($navlink).offset().top-43},"fast");
    }
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("decade-jump-next")) {
        $("html,body").stop(true, true).animate({scrollTop: $($navlink).offset().top},"fast");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Is this animation hardware accelerated? If not, can I somehow force it to be?

Comment: Randomly stumbled across this very old question of mine and now I can tell the past version of me and anyone else reading that jQuery's animate is extraordinarily inefficient and that I should have used something like Greensock to handle the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//html and body don't change in the lifetime of the page, no sense fetching them everytime
//thus we move it out of the handler into a static scope
var html_body = $('html,body');

//Use the context parameter and keep your code short. It acts like `find`.
//I suggest you delegate at a lower parent so bubbling won't travel that far.
//If `.dec-banner` is unique in the page, consider assigning it an `id` instead
//so we can directly access it, rather than find some `class` under some node
//Lastly, you can be more specific rather than listening for events on `a` elements
//that way, the handler won't execute on any `a` element under `.dec-banner`
$('.dec-banner', $timeline).on('click', 'a', function (event) {

  //for values that get used more than once, especially if they require DOM fetching
  //cache their values in variables. In this case, `$(this)` and parent gets used more than once
  var $this = $(this);
  var navlink = $($this.attr('href'));
  var parent = $this.parent();

  //we check for the existence of these classes to determine the fix
  var prev = parent.hasClass('decade-jump-prev');
  var next = parent.hasClass('decade-jump-next');

  event.preventDefault();

  //evaluate if they are prev and next once, rather than twice
  //we can't use the *return early* approach for avoiding indention
  //since propagation might be used
  if (prev || next) {

    //within this block, we assume that the links are either prev or next
    //if not prev, then it should be next

    html_body.stop(true, true).animate({
      //we adjust the fix depending on the existence of prev and next
      //if prev, we use 43, otherwise 0
      scrollTop: navlink.offset().top - (prev ? 43 : 0)
    }, 'fast');
  }


});
```

Comment: this is fantastic! thank you very much. i'm in the beginning stages of learning javascript/jquery so this was extremely helpful.